# ERROR: nes_py-8.1.8-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python

I already have python 3.9.9 and I downloaded the exact file as well for python 3.9 but still I am getting this error.

PS C:\Users\HP> python
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a question? It's a little unclear what you are trying to do. Copying the entire error as well would help